# how to change the path of the images depending of the the button of the menu that I click

Tags: javascript, php

I have a menu in which each section displays a different gallery image. Therefore I have to know what button of the menu I clicked, since depending of the button I have to change the images path.

```
<div id="tabcontainer">
  <ul id="tabnav">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Monuments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Bridges</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Gardens</a></li>
```

For example, if I click on Monuments I have to load the monuments image and if I click on Gardens the gardens image.

I always use the $path variable and I would like to assign it a different path each time.

**EDIT:**

I have 3 path variables, `$path_monumets`, `$path_bridges` and `$path_gardens` but in the end I use the variable `$path`, only `$path`. Depending of the button of the menu that I click I want that the value of `$path` change to `$path=$path_brige` or, `$path=$path_garden`, etc.

Some one could help me? Maybe my question is simply but I couldn't find how to do it on the internet.

THANKS

**EDIT 2**

I wrote the funcion setPath (I know that return the same value but I wanted to use a function ):

```
<?php
function setPath($new_path)
{
return new_path;
}
?>
```

and I changed the menu:

```
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="$path=setPath('<? echo $path_monuments; ?>')">Monuments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="$path=setPath('<? echo $path_bridges; ?>')">Bridges</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" onclick="$path=setPath('<? echo $path_gardens; ?>')">Gardens</a></li>
```

But even so, the variable path doesn't change her value. Could someone help me?

Comment: Load the images where?  What PHP code are you working with?  What javascript have you tried?  You're leaving out the important areas of your question.

Comment: Am I missing something? Why can’t these galleries be on separate pages and you navigate to the relevant gallery when clicking a link? That’s how a menu usually works.

Comment: Axel, I didn't try any javascript code, but I thought that maybe my question could solve using it, for this reason I put the javascript tag. If I am wrong, I apologize. I load the path of the images in the variable $path, I use $path=C:/wamp/www/MyApp/themes/theme/image, but I want to put in that variable each time a different path depending of the button of the menu that I clicked.

Comment: Martin bean, you didn't miss anything. I am starting with php and to be honest I am a bit lost, I didn't think what you said, but maybe it is the best solution. By the way, thanks Martin Bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just move the event to your javascript so that you wont have to modify the mark up at all.

```
...
myTabs[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(e) {
...
```

See a code example in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2B2V5/1/).

Comment: Speedy sorry but I don't understand you...I just use javascript to create some animations, o tell you the truth I don't know javascript. Could you explain your solution to me again? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure. I have added comments to the JSFiddle explaining what you can do with it. http://jsfiddle.net/2B2V5/2/

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is attach the paths to the respectively link:

```
<div id="tabcontainer">
  <ul id="tabnav">
    <li><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="setPath('<? echo $path1; ?>')">Monuments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2" onclick="setPath('<? echo $path2; ?>')">Bridges</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3" onclick="setPath('<? echo $path3; ?>')">Gardens</a></li>
```

So you'll get the path for each link on click. Is that what you want?

Comment: This is good. Just keep in mind that if you are also using any JS libraries like jQuery, setting the onclick attribute can potentially mess with your ability to register other click handlers in your code.

Comment: @rescuecreative Yeah I know, but the OP didn't specified anything but javascript itself, so I'm considering the he's using no framework/library.

Comment: thanks DontVoteMeDown and rescuecreative. I only use php with Yii framework, and I am using a free css, and in the css examples all the galeries were in this document, for this reason I wrote all in the same php page. DontVoteMeDown, I think that I don't explain my idea well. I 'm going to try explain it better in the main post.

Comment: DontVoteMeDown, could you tell me where is defined the setPath fuction? Thanks

Comment: @JK_galera that function you'll have to implement the way you want to deal with the path chosen!

Comment: DontVoteMeDown thanks. I edited the main post. I tried your solution but it doesn't work, I am sure that I am making some mistake.

Comment: @JK_galera yeah you have mixed js and php. The `setPath` function is a JavaScripr function, it can't return a value directly for php. Post **where** you need the path value in your code so I'll tell you how to set it. Is on JavaScript or PHP ?

Comment: DontVoteMeDown, it is on PHP, but in the end I managed to solve my problem! Thanks. I just difined a new value to the path variable inside each `<div id="tabs-NUMBER" class="gallery clear">`